# Ajax not sending parameters to flask

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, flask

I am building a flask app and I am using jquery to send ajax request. I have created two similar ajax request for two different buttons on a same html page. I have done same coding for both ajax request , but one is working and other is not. From what I feel the ajax request that is not working is not sending parameters in post request. 
This is flask code

```
@app.route('/createOrder',methods=['POST','GET'])
def createOrder():
    username = chatusersession[session.get("uname")][1]
    funct = request.form.get('funct')
    if funct == "Create Order":
        if username in ordersession:
            del ordersession[username]
        return render_template('createOrder.html',orderfor=username)
    if funct == "getPaperCode":
        paper_id = request.form.get("papercode")
        crscode = db1.execute("Select course_code from student_master where rollno= :username ",{"username":username}).fetchone()
        try:
            query = db1.execute("Select pap_code,pap_name from subject_master where pap_code= :paper_id and course_code= :crscode",{"paper_id":paper_id,"crscode":crscode[0]}).fetchone()
            if query is None:
                return jsonify({"succes":False,"msg":"No Paper Code found!"})
            else:
                if username not in ordersession:
                    ordersession[username] = {"papers":[query[0],],"discount":None}
                    return jsonify({"succes":True,"papercode":query[0],"papername":query[1]})

                else:
                    if query[0] in ordersession[username]["papers"]:
                        return jsonify({"succes":False,"msg":"You have already added this paper"})
                    else:
                        ordersession[username]["papers"].append[query[0]]
                        return jsonify({"succes":True,"papercode":query[0],"papername":query[1]})
        except:
            return jsonify({"succes":False,"msg":"Can not lookup! Try again Later."})
    if funct == "deletepaper":
        paper_id = request.form.get("papercode")
        if paper_id in ordersession[username]["papers"]:
            ordersession[username]["papers"].remove(paper_id)
            return jsonify({"succes":True,"msg":"Deleted Successfuly"})
        else:
            return jsonify({"succes":False,"msg":"Can not delete , Some error"})
```

This is javascript , The ajax function defined on top is not working, whereas the second ajax function is working fine .. the code to send request is identical

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#deletepaper').on('submit',function(event) {

        $.ajax ({
            data: {
                papercode : $('#papercodeinput').val() ,
                funct : $('#functid').val()
            },
            type : 'POST',
            url : '/createOrder'
        })
        .done(function(data){
            if(data.succes) {
                console.log("Hello success");
                console.log(data.msg);
                $('.table tbody').on('click','.btn',function(){
                    $(this).closet('tr').rmeove();
                });
            }
            else {
                console.log("Hello not success");

                document.getElementById("alert").innerHTML = data.msg;
            }

        });
    });
    });
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#getpaper').on('submit',function(event) {

        $.ajax ({
            data: {
                papercode : $('.papercodeinput').val() ,
                funct : $('#functid').val()
            },
            type : 'POST',
            url : '/createOrder'
        })
        .done(function(data){
            if(data.succes) {
                console.log("Hello success");
                console.log(data);
                var table = document.getElementById("paperlist");
                var row = table.insertRow(-1);
                var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
                var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
                var cell3 = row.insertCell(2);
                var cell4 = row.insertCell(3);
                cell1.innerHTML = `<form id="deletepaper"><input type="hidden" id="papercodeinput" value=${data.papercode}><input type="hidden" id="functid" value='deletepaper'><button type="submit" class="btn">X</button></form>`;
                cell2.innerHTML = data.papercode;
                cell3.innerHTML = data.papername;
                cell4.innerHTML = "<input>"
            }
            else {
                console.log(data.msg);
            }

        });
        document.querySelector('.papercodeinput').value = "";
        event.preventDefault();
    });

});
```

html code is

```
<div class='container'>
            <div class="order">
                <p><h3>Order for : {{ orderfor }}</h3></p>
                <form id="getpaper">
                <label>Paper Code</label>
                <input type="text" class='papercodeinput'>
                <p id="alert"></p>

                <input type='hidden' id="functid" name='funct' value='getPaperCode'>
                <button type="submit" id="addpaper" name='addpaper'>Add Paper</button>
                </form>
                <table id="paperlist">
                    <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>F</th>
                        <th>PaperCode</th>
                        <th>Paper Name</th>
                        <th>Expected Marks/Grade</th>

                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>

                </tbody>
                </table>
```

When working with first ajax request , flask is throwing an error

"The view function did not return a valid response. The"
TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response. The function either returned None or ended without a return statement.127.0.0.1 "

Which I understand is because when ajax reaches server there is no return request received. And on server side `"if funct == "deletepaper":"`  this code receives this ajax request . I think the parameter is not being passed to server that is why non of the if query works and nothing is returned ..

Also the first ajax request which is not working and I have mentioned method = POST , it is still being sent as GET request. and with no parameters.

Please help ..
Thanks in advance :)